# how to undo cvWarpPerspective

Tags: c, opencv

I found a program that change the perspective, like

[image: source]

[image: result]

My question is how can get back to the source image, and get the coordinates of the red point the draw in the second image ? 
here's the code :

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    CvPoint2D32f srcQuad[4], dstQuad[4];
    CvMat* warp_matrix = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
    IplImage *src, *dst;
    src=cvLoadImage("b.jpg",1) ;
    dst = cvCloneImage(src);
    dst->origin = src->origin;
    cvZero(dst);
        srcQuad[0].x = 0; //src Top left
    srcQuad[0].y = 0;
    srcQuad[1].x = src->width - 1; //src Top right
    srcQuad[1].y = 0;
    srcQuad[2].x = 0; //src Bottom left
    srcQuad[2].y = src->height - 1;
    srcQuad[3].x = src->width -1; //src Bot right
    srcQuad[3].y = src->height - 1;
    dstQuad[0].x = src->width*0.05; //dst Top left
    dstQuad[0].y = src->height*0.33;
    dstQuad[1].x = src->width*0.9; //dst Top right
    dstQuad[1].y = src->height*0.25;
    dstQuad[2].x = src->width*0.2; //dst Bottom left
    dstQuad[2].y = src->height*0.7;
    dstQuad[3].x = src->width*0.8; //dst Bot right
    dstQuad[3].y = src->height*0.9;
    cvGetPerspectiveTransform(
    srcQuad,
    dstQuad,
    warp_matrix
    );
    cvWarpPerspective( src, dst, warp_matrix );
    cvNamedWindow( "Perspective_Warp", 1 );
    cvShowImage( "Perspective_Warp", dst );
    cvSaveImage("bbb.jpg",dst);
    cvWaitKey();

     cvReleaseImage(&dst);
    cvReleaseMat(&warp_matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

after the suggestion of @mrgloom I can go back to the first perspective.

```
cvInvert(warp_matrix,inversematrix);
cvWarpPerspective( dst, src2, inversematrix );
cvNamedWindow( "2", 2 );
cvShowImage( "2", src2 );
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: You don't even need the explicit inverse. You can just pass the `CV_WARP_INVERSE_MAP` flag to `cvWarpPerspective()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

formula for perspective transform, where m_{i,j} is homography matrix elements

```
   u= (m11*x + m12*y + m13)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33); 
   v= (m21*x + m22*y + m23)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
```

so backward transformation will be

```
x = (-V * m33 * m12 + V * m32 * m13 + m23 * m12 - m22 * m13 + m22 * U * m33 - m23 * U * m32) / (m11 * m22 - m11 * V * m32 - m12 * m21 + m12 * V * m31 - U * m31 * m22 + U * m32 * m21);
t2 = m11 * V;
t7 = U * m31;
y = -(m11 * m23 - t2 * m33 - m13 * m21 + m13 * V * m31 - t7 * m23 + U * m33 * m21) / (m11 * m22 - t2 * m32 - m12 * m21 + m12 * V * m31 - t7 * m22 + U * m32 * m21);
```

So you can calculate any point correspondence (x,y)->(u,v) and (u,v)->(x,y) using homography matrix.

I'm not sure but I think backward transform also can be obtained by inverting homography matrix (warp_matrix in your case)

Comment: use invert http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_operations_on_arrays.html#invert  to invert warp_matrix and then use cvWarpPerspective(dst,src, invert_warp_matrix );  for backward transform

Comment: thanks again for your comment I tried again and it  partially works, because I can get back to the source image but its dimensions are smaller! see the update ! and thanks again

Comment: never mind it works, I'll try to find a way to get a point coordinate and not the whole picture thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
cvGetPerspectiveTransform(
    dstQuad,
    srcQuad,
    inverse_matrix
    );
cvPerspectiveTransform(RedDotDistorted, RedDotRectified, inverse_matrix);
```

Check out [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827658/how-to-undo-cvwarpperspective/17834789#17834789) Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: the question's link isn't working and where do you got RedDotDistorted  and RedRectified ??

Comment: It's a 3D vector of the coordinates of your distorted red dot (this is an input right?) whose original coordinate you want. With Z=0. Actually that 3D vector is contained in a sparse matrix that is called RedDotDistorted. It may be good to read up on how to create/read/write a sparse matrix.

Comment: well the red dot isn't 3D it's only 2D, in both perspectives and I assume the inverse matrix well be the inverse of the warpMatrix , and talking about the SparseMatrix I alreasy tried to work with but it didnT' work I assume that I don't understand what it really does ! if you don't mind would you please write a part of the code so I can understand it! thanks in advance